# Unicode characters in XeLatex

Tags: fonts, xetex

This is my LaTex script:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Jenson Classico}
\begin{document}
ąęśćłó
\end{document}
```

I compile this using xelatex through eclipse plugin.

As Jenson Classico has no polish characters I have edited this font to add them. In Microsoft Office it works fine (I am able to use polish characters). Unfortunately in pdf generated from above tex-file it doesn't. If I use any other font (e.g. Arial) it works like a dream.

Any suggesions? I really don't have any more ideas...

---

This is part of the log file:

```
Requested font "Jenson Classico" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/WINNT/Fonts/Jenson.ttf
Requested font "Jenson Classico/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/WINNT/Fonts/Jenson.ttf
 fontspec Info: Font Jenson Classico does not contain any OpenType `Script' inf
ormation.

\c@zf@famc@Jenson Classico=\count151
 fontspec Info: Defining font family for 'Jenson Classico' with options [Mappin
g=tex-text].

Package fontspec Info: Defining shape m/n with raw font features:
(fontspec)             mapping=tex-text;.
Requested font "Jenson Classico/B/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/WINNT/Fonts/Jenson.ttf
 fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Jenson Classico/B (it probably doesn't e
xist).

Requested font "Jenson Classico/I/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/WINNT/Fonts/Jenson.ttf
 fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Jenson Classico/I (it probably doesn't e
xist).

Requested font "Jenson Classico/BI/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/WINNT/Fonts/Jenson.ttf
 fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Jenson Classico/BI (it probably doesn't 
exist).

Requested font "Jenson Classico/ICU:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/WINNT/Fonts/Jenson.ttf

[...]

Missing character: There is no ą in font Jenson Classico/ICU:mapping=tex-text;
!
Missing character: There is no ę in font Jenson Classico/ICU:mapping=tex-text;
!
Missing character: There is no ś in font Jenson Classico/ICU:mapping=tex-text;
!
Missing character: There is no ć in font Jenson Classico/ICU:mapping=tex-text;
!
```

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of the font installed, e.g., both with and without these characters? If so, be sure to remove the other one.

Comment: No. Folder C:\WINNT\Fonts contains only one file jenson.ttf

Comment: Well xelatex can search other places too. Also you are calling the font by its internal name and there can be other fonts with this name. Put \XeTeXtracingfonts=1 in your document and call xelatex on the command line with the option --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv". This should show you in the log and on the terminal which fonts xetex + xdvipdfmx are actually using.

Answer (score 2):

What does the log file say? If XeTeX thinks the font is missing characters you'll get in the log file

```
Missing character: There is no ä in font [...]!
```